# Is there any way by which we can do long polling in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, polling

I want to get the latest value of a `custom field (Complete__c)` on the Opportunity. This field gets updated after a trigger runs on the child object of Opportunity on some button click on the UI built with LWC.

I was thinking of querying the field by using a `set timeout`, but that seems to be an imperfect logic where we would have to give some magic number for the timeout. Is there a way by which I can Identify the field on opportunity has updated and then let the LWC component know the same?

Please guide me if you any of you has some idea on the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [EMP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) which allows you to listen for update events. This is efficient, using a single cometD connection even if there are multiple listeners in the lightning page. You just need to make sure to set up a message channel and listen for the update messages as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the poster above (PhilW).

Additionally, note that the LWC consumption of platform events counts as an "External Subscriber" to the event bus, which counts against 2 governor limits: # of events delivered external per day (50k-100k for free, additional small cost for more events), and # of external subscribers (max 2000 per org).
Internal Subscribers (triggers and flows) have no limit to the number of events they receive per day.

This architecture is fine for smaller orgs where you have less than 2000 users looking at oppties at the same time. This arch would not work for large call centers.